# GUI Text Alignment

Tags: java, swing, alignment, layout-manager

I am working on a Battleship program, and I have encountered a slight mishap. I want to label the two grids (user and computer) and so I am using the GridBagLayout to control the size of the components. Now, when I go to center the text to put it in the middle of the label it's in, it does not do anything, it stays in the same place. Here is my code:

```
package buttongrid;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.border.Border;

public class ButtonGrid {

        JFrame frame=new JFrame(); //creates frame
        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
        JPanel panel3 = new JPanel();
        JPanel panel4 = new JPanel();
        JPanel panel5 = new JPanel();
        JPanel panel6 = new JPanel();
        JLabel label1 = new JLabel();
        JLabel label2 = new JLabel();
        JLabel[][] grid; //names the grid of buttons
        JLabel[][] enemyGrid;
        String COLS = "ABCDEFGHIJK";
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        Border border = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 1);

        public ButtonGrid() throws MalformedURLException{ //constructor
            URL urlPic = new URL("http://i47.tinypic.com/14wswi9.gif");
            ImageIcon waterPic = new ImageIcon(urlPic);

                frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout()); //set layout
                frame.setResizable(false);

                //ADDING TOP LEFT PANEL
                label1.setText("Your Grid");
                label1.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);
                label1.setVerticalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);
                panel4.add(label1);
                panel4.setBorder(border);
                c.gridx = 0;
                c.gridy = 0;
                c.ipady = 10;
                frame.add(panel4, c);

                //ADDING TOP MIDDLE PANEL
                panel5.setBorder(border);
                c.gridx = 1;
                c.gridy = 0;
                c.ipady = 10;
                frame.add(panel5, c);

                //ADDING TOP MIDDLE PANEL
                label2.setText("Enemy Grid");
                label2.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);
                label2.setVerticalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);
                panel6.add(label2);
                panel6.setBorder(border);
                c.gridx = 2;
                c.gridy = 0;
                c.ipady = 10;
                frame.add(panel6, c);

                //USER GRID
                c.gridx = 0;
                c.gridy = 1;
                panel1.setLayout(new GridLayout(11,11));
                grid=new JLabel[11][11]; //allocate the size of grid
                for(int y=0; y<11; y++){
                        for(int x=0; x<11; x++){
                            ImageIcon icon2 = new ImageIcon(new BufferedImage(32, 32, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB));
                                grid[x][y]= new JLabel(icon2);
                                grid[x][y].setBorder(border);
                                panel1.add(grid[x][y]); 
                        }
                }

                frame.add(panel1, c);

                for(int y=1; y<11; y++){
                    grid[y][0].setText(Integer.toString(y));
                    grid[y][0].setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);
                        for(int x=1; x<11; x++){
                            grid[x][y].setIcon(waterPic);
                        }
                }

                for(int x = 1; x < 11; x++){
                    grid[0][x].setText(COLS.substring(x - 1, x));
                    grid[0][x].setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);
                }

                //EMPTY SPACE IN BETWEEN GRIDS
                c.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
                c.gridx = 1;
                c.gridy = 1;
                c.ipadx = 10;
                panel2.setBorder(border);
                frame.add(panel2, c);

                //ENEMY GRID
                c.gridx = 2;
                c.gridy = 1;
                panel3.setLayout(new GridLayout(11,11));
                enemyGrid=new JLabel[11][11]; //allocate the size of grid
                for(int y=0; y<11; y++){
                        for(int x=0; x<11; x++){
                            ImageIcon icon2 = new ImageIcon(new BufferedImage(32, 32, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB));
                                enemyGrid[x][y]= new JLabel(icon2); //  
                                enemyGrid[x][y].setBorder(border);
                                panel3.add(enemyGrid[x][y]); //
                        }
                }

                frame.add(panel3, c);

                for(int y=1; y<11; y++){
                    enemyGrid[y][0].setText(Integer.toString(y));
                    enemyGrid[y][0].setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);
                        for(int x=1; x<11; x++){
                            enemyGrid[x][y].setIcon(waterPic);
                        }
                }

                for(int x = 1; x < 11; x++){
                    enemyGrid[0][x].setText(COLS.substring(x - 1, x));
                    enemyGrid[0][x].setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);
                }

                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.pack(); //sets appropriate size for frame
                frame.setVisible(true); //makes frame visible
        }
        public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException{
                new ButtonGrid();//makes new ButtonGrid with 2 parameters
        }
}
```

I included a border around every component in the frame, just to make things easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean the header labels...

[image]

This is been caused by the layout manager and not the label itself.  `JPanel` uses a `FlowLayout` by default.  Consider using a different layout manager, for example, `GridBagLayout` for example

```
JPanel panel4 = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
JPanel panel6 = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
```

[image]

If you want more padding about the labels, you could use a `CompoundBorder` and mix the current border with an `EmptyBorder` or use `GridBagConstraints` to define additional insets...

For example...

```
GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
gbc.insets = new Insets(8, 8, 8, 8);

//...
panel4.add(label1, gbc);
//...
panel6.add(label2, gbc);
```

[image]

You might get a better result though, you break the UI down into sections.  The grid is repeatable component, so start by making the grid a component of it's own.

You could use a `BorderLayout` to position the title and the grid itself and then using another container, add the `GridPanel`s using a `GridLayout` to get them side by side, for example...

Comment: +1, for identifying the layout manager of the panels as the problem.

Comment: Ahhh ok I see, I'll definitely try this out and see if it works, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Based on Mad's suggestion that the problem is the layout manager of the panel, I would go one step further and say that you don't even need a JPanel to hold the labels. Just add the labels directly to the grid and then you even need to worry about the panels.

You can control the desired spacing you want by using a Border on each label. For example you could create a Border like:

```
Border labelBorder = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 10, 5, 10);
```

Then the code for adding the label to the grid would be:

```
label1.setBorder(labelBorder);
//panel4.add(label1);
//panel4.setBorder(border);
c.gridx = 0;
c.gridy = 0;
//c.ipady = 10;
//frame.add(panel4, c);
frame.add(label1, c);
```

For the middle component you can just create a JLabel with no text. The Border will then occupy the entire space which will control the horizontal space you have between the two grids.

Also, there is no need create the BufferedImages to use them as an Icon. The size of the grid will be determined by the size of your "water" image.

To center the text in the grid you should be using the following method:

```
label.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
```

the default for vertical alignment is CENTER so you don't need to worry about that.

Comment: For the BufferedImages thing, I think I do need it as the numbers row and the letters column will be smaller than I need them to be, so I set everything to a default size in the grid as nothing else will change.

Comment: @user3741402, the cell size is the same for all cells in a GridLayout. The largest component added to the grid determines the size for all cells in the grid.